# AWS SNS sending multiple emails all at once

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have set up SNS email SNS on my lambda function which would send the AWS Credentials to my email to which I have subscribed.

However, when I run the lambda function I get sent the same email multiple times all at once I have attached the below screenshot. I have to unsubscribe in order for the emails to stop spamming my account.

[image: AWS notifications]

Below is the lambda function I have got which sends the SNS email notification:

```
import boto3
import base64
import json 
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    secret_name = "test/Secret"
    
    
    region_name = "eu-west-2"

    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )
    
    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId = secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailureException':
            # Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InternalServiceErrorException':
            # An error occurred on the server side.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
            # You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
            # You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
            # We can't find the resource that you asked for.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
    # else:
    #     # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
    #     # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
    #     if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
    #         secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
    #     else:
    #         decoded_binary_secret = base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])
    
    else:
        # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
        # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
        else:
            secret = base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])
            
     # Send message to SNS
    MY_SNS_TOPIC_ARN = 'arn:aws:sns:TOPIC_ARN'
    sns_client = boto3.client('sns')
    sns_client.publish(
        TopicArn = MY_SNS_TOPIC_ARN,
        Message = 'Your Credentians are: ' + secret
    )        

    return json.loads(secret)  # returns the secret as dictionary
```

Any solutions to how I can resolve the spamming of the email and just receive 1 email when the lambda is invoked?

Comment: How often is your lambda invoked, does it produce any errors? Maybe include the request id and a timestamp somewhere in the email to backtrace from which invocation the email originated.

Comment: i manually  invoked the lambda once, it sent over 100 Plus SNS notifications, i have looked at the logs no errors are produced

Comment: And the lambda only shows logs from one invocation? And how many subscriptions are there on the topic?

Comment: shows 1 invocation but it sens multiple sns notifications via email. 2 subscriptions: 1 my email and 2: lambda function subscription  to topic

Comment: Which lambda? If you subscribe the same lambda to the topic it will trigger a notification that triggers an email and the lambda which triggers a notification which triggers a email and the lambda which triggers ....

Comment: sorry the above lambda sens the credentials to the sns which i have subscribed, when invoked it send the credentials to my email

Comment: Again: if that lambda both sends a message to SNS ***and*** listens / is subscribed to SNS then you have an infinite loop.

Comment: thank you for the clarification I was not aware that would cause an infinite loop. Should I remove the lambda subscriptions?

Comment: of course :) why would you have the subscription there in the first place? Note that you absolutely should see multiple invocations in the logs in that case.